# How to get simple box to render in scenekit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Hey I have Apples default SceneKit learning file called "Fox" And I wanted to see if I can put one of my own 3D objects in there game. So I started with the just a simple square literally a box. All I did was replace the name Panda with the name of the box in the code. I original exported the box as a .dae then when I put it In Xcode a converted it to SCN no problem. It builds fine. but now when I run the game with my box it say bad access. it seems like it has something to do with "characterTopLevel" Any Help.

Code:

```
 class Character {

// MARK: Initialization

init() {

    // MARK: Load character from external file

    // The character is loaded from a .scn file and stored in an intermediate
    // node that will be used as a handle to manipulate the whole group at once


    let characterScene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/Box.scn")!
    let characterTopLevelNode = characterScene.rootNode.childNodes[0]
    node.addChildNode(characterTopLevelNode)
```

It works fine when I use the default file "3D Character Panda"

Code:

```
    let characterScene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/Panda.dae")!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvbi4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wXxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

your file is named `Box.scn` and so you probably meant

```
let characterScene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/Box.scn")!
```

Comment: It was just a typo on here but its named .scn haha i fixed it thanks though

Comment: Hi @mnuages would it be okay to email you about a potential project? Thanks!